# Compilation crashes

Tags: packages

I want my chapter titles to be in english but the compilation crashes if I delete \usepackage{french}.
Do you know what I should do?
Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{french}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
% Font style definition

% Interline setting
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{#1\vss}}
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{#3}}%
}
\newcommand\AtTopCenterPage[2]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#1}){\blap{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}%
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{\llap{#3}}}%
}

\title{\huge{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}}
\author{\textsc{Corongiu} Chiara}
\date{\today}
\makeatletter
 \geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \AddToShipoutPicture{
        \AtUpperLeftCorner{1.5cm}{1.8cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{pgarde/uliege.jpg}}
       % \AtTopCenterPage{1.5cm}{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{pgarde/mms_logo.png}}
        \AtUpperRightCorner{1.5cm}{0.6cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pgarde/Sonaca2.png}}
    }

    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{5cm}
        \HRule
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textsc{\textbf{\@title}}
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \HRule
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \LARGE{\textit{Master thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
for the degree of Master in Aerospace Engineering by\\ \vspace{0.2cm}} \@author}\\
    \end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
 \large{University of Liège - Faculty of Applied Sciences\\
Academic year 2019-2020}   
\end{center}



  %  \begin{center}
  %      \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{data/footer.jpg}}
 %   \end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\ClearShipoutPicture
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\english
\chapter*{Abstract}
\newpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{Powder characterisation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `\usepackage{french}` if the text is in English?

Comment: I only get errors for the missing JPEG files. Update your TeX distribution and retry.

Comment: This is the kind of newbies I love most: ask a question and _never_ come back. Profile today says: »Last seen Sep 12 at 14:52«.

Comment: well maybe Iam busy ;)

Answer (score 1):

The package `french` seems outdated, better to use babel, which definetely is a mainline package.

After deleting `\usepackage{french}`it is necessary to delete the *.aux, *.toc, *.log and *.lot files, in short, the auxiliary files LaTeX produced on the way to get a *.pdf. ***Beware not to delete the *.tex file!!!***

I changed your code in some places:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
%\usepackage{french}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
% Font style definition

\usepackage{blindtext}

% Interline setting
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{#1\vss}}
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{#3}}%
}
\newcommand\AtTopCenterPage[2]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#1}){\blap{\hbox to 0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}%
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
  \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-#1},\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperheight-#2}){\blap{\llap{#3}}}%
}

\title{\huge{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}}
\author{\textsc{Corongiu} Chiara}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\let\myauthor\@author
\let\mydate\@date
\makeatother

%\makeatletter
 \geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=3cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    % \AddToShipoutPicture{
    %     \AtUpperLeftCorner{1.5cm}{1.8cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{pgarde/uliege.jpg}}
    %    % \AtTopCenterPage{1.5cm}{1cm}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{pgarde/mms_logo.png}}
    %     \AtUpperRightCorner{1.5cm}{0.6cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{pgarde/Sonaca2.png}}
    % }

    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{5cm}
        \HRule
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \textsc{\textbf{\mytitle}}
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \HRule
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \LARGE{\textit{Master thesis submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements\\
for the degree of Master in Aerospace Engineering by\\ \vspace{0.2cm}} \myauthor}\\
    \end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
 \large{University of Liège - Faculty of Applied Sciences\\
Academic year 2019-2020}   
\end{center}



  %  \begin{center}
  %      \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{data/footer.jpg}}
 %   \end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\ClearShipoutPicture
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\blindtext{}

\selectlanguage{french}

\blindtext{}

\newpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter*{Introduction}

\chapter{Powder characterisation}
\end{document}
```

Compile it (twice) an you'll get under ABSTRACT text in english and french.

But if you main question were, how to change the language automagically in all sections, so that the language of chapters and sections would be english, while the text would be french, please edit you question.

By the way: you get the manual of each package with `texdoc packagename` on the command line (under Windows: cmd.exe). Try `texdoc -s packagename`.

Comment: To the contrary, `french.sty` has been updated on 2019/09/06.

Comment: @egreg So it’s the other way round: I‘m outdated!

Comment: I tried your code but it doesnt work for me :(

Comment: I use overleaf to compile the code

Comment: @ChiaraCorongiu: The  `french` package, since its author Bernard Gaulle was deceased has been maintained by a staff of three persons under yhe name `efrench`.